# Ionic 4 with xcode 10 ios build fails with device parameter. No ipa generated

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, xcode10, ionic4, code-signing-certificate

I am using Ionic 4, Cordova 8, and XCode 10.  Before Ionic 4, I used to be able to run this command to generate both the .xcarchive and the .ipa.

```
ionic cordova build ios --device --release --buildConfig=build.json
```

Now, my build.json file has:

```
{
    "ios": {    
        "release": {
            "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
            "developmentTeam": "123465ABCD",
            "packageType": "app-store",
            "automaticProvisioning": true,
            "buildFlag": [
                "-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Without the *--device* argument, the ios project compiles just fine without error, and it produces a signed .app file. But **I don't get a .IPA file, which is what I really want.**

When I try to run a build with --device, I get the following error:

> Code Signing Error: No signing certificate "iOS Development" found: 
>   No "iOS Development" signing certificate matching team ID "123465ABCD"
>   with a private key was found.
>
> Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type
>   'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'
>
> ** ARCHIVE FAILED **

I don't understand why an "iOS Development" development certificate is even being asked for, since I specifically said this was a production release, with a codeSignIdentity for "iPhone Developer". Regardless, **I need to generate a signed .IPA**, based on the device and not emulator platform.

Please note: I do NOT have access to the XCode project IDE, so I need to use CLIs entirely for an automated build process.

Comment: I'm starting to think that I had an old or out-dated signing certificate on the build server that Xcode somehow remembers....